# Solrj random sorting

Tags: solr, solrj

I'd like to know if it's possible to return a SolrDocument in my response, specifying first a query that return for instance the 100 most expensive products and afterwards return randomly only 1 product to my application.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think solr will return you with a single query for your needs, you want 100 most expensive ( This itself is based on criteria ) and then a last record with random product.

As per my knowledge, you will have to use 2 queries to get the results out. before this you have to include a random field sort in your solr.xml as illustrated below :

Use a RandomSortField in your solr.xml . There's an example in the bundled schema.xml in example directory of solr downloads (under solr folder ):

```
<fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

<dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />
```

This will Sort your result list by the field random_, where you replace  with a randomly generated value (but use the same value if you're paginating through the result, as it will give you a stable sort based on the field name).

Modify these in solr.xml as illustrated above, and fire 2 queries, merge the result & return back.

1. fire a query ?q=*&sort=prod_amt desc&rows=100 ( Assuming your product amount is in field by name 'prod_amt' ) - This will give you top 100 expensive products.
2. fire a query ?q=*&sort=random_12939291 desc&rows=1 ( Here 12939291 is just a random string ).

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Shiva Kumar SS